# What happens if forked Gist is deleted?

Tags: github, gist

This question is to know if I need to keep a backup of [my forked Gists](https://gist.github.com/tiago-peres) or not.

There's a similar question that addresses [What happens to the forks when deleting the original repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53052745/5675325).

So, basically, I want to know what happens to my fork if the original Gist is deleted. Do I still get to keep the forks when they were made from a public Gist ([like in GitHub repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954210/5675325))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted support and the answer from Robert Norrie (GitHub Support) was

> If the original gist is deleted, any forks simply lose their fork
> relationship with the original and become a standalone gist. They
> don't get deleted.

So, no need to do the backups.