# Unable to transfer github repository because of fork with same name

Tags: github

I'm trying to help a client organize their github repositories.  What happened is that I started a git hub repository `john/project-alpha` and we pushed all our changes and proof-of-concept work to that repository. Somewhere along the way, our proof-of-concept project grew into a real project and we made a git fork `abc-corporation/project-alpha`, and started pushing all our work there.

In the past, I noticed that if I delete the original repository, the forked repository also disappears.  For example, if I delete `john/project-alpha`, then `abc-corporation/project-alpha` is also destroyed.  So this time I tried to transfer `john/project-alpha` to the user `abc-corporation`.  But when I do so, github complains that `abc-corporation` already has a repository of the same name.

What is the best way to make `abc-corporation/project-alpha` the **only repository** such that our team never pushes to `john/project-alpha` ever again?

Comment: When you delete a private repo all private forks are also deleted (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53052745/3001761). But you still have the repo locally, presumably; why not create a new empty repo with the appropriate name, update your remotes and push to that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I can start a new repo based on our local repo if that's the best practice. Wasn't sure if there was a better way

Comment: "Better" *how*; is there data beyond the commits you're trying to migrate, for example?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I was concerned there might be some commits/branches in `john/project-alpha` that are not in `abc-corporation/project-alpha` and vice versa.  And thought maybe there was an action that does something like `github merge abc-corporation/project-alpha.git john/project-alpha.git`.